# MySQL - join tables

Tags: mysql

I need to do a SELECT from the following two tables to the result table:

**flight_connection**

| flight number | departure | arrival |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 310 | NUE | TXL |
| 926 | FRA | NUE |
| 312 | TXL | NUE |

**airport**

| code | description |
| --- | --- |
| NUE | Nuremberg |
| FRA | Frankfurt |
| TXL | Berlin-Tegel |

**RESULT TABLE:**

| code | description | departures | arrivals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NUE | Nuremberg | 1 | 2 |
| FRA | Frankfurt | 1 | 0 |
| TXL | Berlin-Tegel | 1 | 1 |

This is for counting all departures and arrivals for each airport and if one does not have a departure or arrival then it must be filled with 0 and not NULL.

I have so far gotten a table for either arrival or departure but not together, I've tried with UNION ALL but this just merges departures and arrivals count, I'm a little lost and would appreciate a little help.

**Departure**

```
    SELECT DISTINCT code, description, Count(departure) AS departures FROM 
    (
        SELECT code, description, departure FROM airport
            INNER JOIN flight_connection ON departure = code
    ) as tmptbl
    GROUP BY code, description
```

**Arrival**

```
    SELECT DISTINCT code, description, Count(arrival) AS arrivals FROM 
    (
        SELECT code, description, arrivalFROM airport
            INNER JOIN flight_connection ON arrival = code
    ) as tmptbl
    GROUP BY code, description
```

Comment: Did you check the UNION operation documentation? https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without a suquery only with two joins

> ```
> CREATE TABLE flight_connection (
>   `flight number` INTEGER,
>   `departure` VARCHAR(3),
>   `arrival` VARCHAR(3)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO flight_connection
>   (`flight number`, `departure`, `arrival`)
> VALUES
>   ('310', 'NUE', 'TXL'),
>   ('926', 'FRA', 'NUE'),
>   ('312', 'TXL', 'NUE');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE airport (
>   `code` VARCHAR(3),
>   `description` VARCHAR(12)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO airport
>   (`code`, `description`)
> VALUES
>   ('NUE', 'Nuremberg'),
>   ('FRA', 'Frankfurt'),
>   ('TXL', 'Berlin-Tegel');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `code`,`description`,IFNULL(departures,0) as departures,IFNULL(arrivals,0) as arrivals FROM airport a
> LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) arrivals,`arrival` FROM flight_connection GROUP BY `arrival`) f1 ON a.`code` = f1.`arrival` 
> LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) departures,`departure` FROM flight_connection GROUP BY `departure`) f2 ON a.`code` = f2.`departure`
> ```
>
> ```
> code | description  | departures | arrivals
> :--- | :----------- | ---------: | -------:
> NUE  | Nuremberg    |          1 |        2
> FRA  | Frankfurt    |          1 |        0
> TXL  | Berlin-Tegel |          1 |        1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a88f9e630eea7f3f11b963d54a2af732)*

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. That is way more elegant than what i was trying to do

Answer (score 0):

mysql
use 2 sql like postgresql (see below) replacing FULL OUTER JOIN by LEFT JOIN for the first one and RIGHT JOIN for the second one.

And the use this answer

[How to do a FULL OUTER JOIN in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/how-to-do-a-full-outer-join-in-mysql)

postgresql

Union is to 'merge' rows, join for column

```
SELECT code,desciption,departures, arrivals FROM

( SELECT DISTINCT code, description, Count(departure) AS departures FROM 
    (
        SELECT code, description, departure FROM airport
            INNER JOIN flight_connection ON departure = code
    ) as tmptbl
    GROUP BY code, description ) r1

FULL OUTER JOIN 

   (  SELECT DISTINCT code, description, Count(arrival) AS arrivals FROM 
    (
        SELECT code, description, arrivalFROM airport
            INNER JOIN flight_connection ON arrival = code
    ) as tmptbl
    GROUP BY code, description ) r2

USING (code,description);
```

You can use coalesce function to chnage Null to 0 if you want.

Comment: This only gives me all the airports that have arrivals and departures, if an airport only has arrivals or only departures it will not be displayed in this table

Comment: Corrected - FULL OUTER JOIN

Comment: MySQL has no FULL OUTER JOIN You have to UNION a LEFT and RIGHT JOIN

Comment: Right, I'm used to postgresql, let me check how to dot it in mysql ...